# How to get a reference to the tail of a tuple from an object std::tuple<Head,Tail...>

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17

I have defined:

```
template<class Head,class ...Tail>
struct elem{
    std::tuple<Head,Tail...> dm;
};
```

I have the functions head(), tail() and others for the class elem, but they create copies, they return a copy of the head of tuple or the tail of tuple, but I need a reference to the tail of this->dm.

For the head is easy, `std::get<0>(this->dm)` give me the reference.

Is it possible for the tail? By tail, I mean all the elements after the first one.

Comment: By "tail", do you mean the last element of the `tuple`?

Comment: Please, define "reference to the tail".

Comment: No, I want mean if the list is {0,1,2,3} then the tail is {1,2,3}. The idea is get<1>(dm),get<2>(dm),...,get<tuple_size(dm)-1>(dm), but a reference to the total as a tuple.

Comment: C++ isn't Prolog: the "tail" isn't a `std::tuple`. Or, if it is, is in the compiler-specific implementation details.

Comment: I write the get<0>(dm), but if I consider the remainder of the tuple dm (without the head==get<0>(dm)) and I name this reaminder as the tail, I need a reference to the tail to write in this tail.

Comment: The best I can imagine, as "reference to the tail", is a reference to the second element. But it's a reference to the second element, not to all following elements seen as a `std::tuple<Tail...>`. I don't think exist such reference (excluding possible compiler-specific implementation details).

Comment: I had coded this as template<typename Head,typename ... Tail> struct elem {Head dm; elem<Tail...> rdm;}; and then I worked by recursion. Now, if I work with a simple std::tuple, I need a reference to the "rdm".

Comment: In the other hand I can work by indices. But it is annoying.

Comment: Yes: *you* have coded `elem` recursively; but we don't know how is coded `std::tuple` and every implementation is coded in a different way; there isn't nothing, at standard level, as a `std::tuple<Tail...>` member element in `std::tuple<Head, Tail...>`; see also the Barry's answer for a better explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a thing would only be possible if a `tuple<A, B, C>` were stored internally as something equivalent to a cons cell:

```
struct __tuple_A_B_C {
    A car;
    tuple<B, C> cdr;

    A& head() { return car; }
    tuple<B, C>& tail() { return cdr; }
};
```

But that isn't the case - all you know is that you have subobjects of types `A`, `B`, and `C`. Their layout is completely unspecified -  and you definitely don't know whether or not implementations use recursion like this to implement `tuple`. They're allowed to, but I'm not sure any do.

The best you could do is, given a `tuple<A, B, C>` return a `tuple<B&, C&>`. In C++17, that's not so bad to implement:

```
template<class Head,class ...Tail>
struct elem{
    std::tuple<Head,Tail...> dm;

    auto tail() {
        return std::apply([](auto&, auto&... rest){
            return std::tie(rest...);
        }, dm);
    }
};
```

---

But if you really want this recursive cons-cell-like approach, you're probably better off actually implementing your own recursion so you get the desired behavior:

```
template <class Head, class... Tail>
struct elem {
    Head head;
    elem<Tail...> tail;
};

template <class Head>
struct elem<Head> {
    Head head;
};
```

Depends on what you're actually doing.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected something that you say.